# Excel VBA - Run Time Error 13 (Stuck on the +1 formula)

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing a scanning Barcode system by using form. 
This is how the form works:

1. User will scan the barcode into "Packing QR Code Serial Number".
2. Form will compare "Packing QR Code Serial Number" with "Part QR Code Serial Number". If same, shows "OK". Then, **the last 7 number is choosen out and increase 1**; if not, show "NG" and setfocus back to "Packing QR Code Serial Number".

However, Excel showed "Run Time Error 13" and stuck on the +1 formula".
May I know why is this happen? Any mistake on the code ?
Thanks

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
Private Sub PackingSNTextBox_AfterUpdate()

Dim emptyRow As Long, Temp1 As String, Temp1A As Long, Temp1B As String, Temp2 As String, Temp11 As Long, Temp1AA As String, Temp3 As String

'Make Sheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate
PartSNTextBox.Enabled = True

If PartSNTextBox.Value = PackingSNTextBox.Value Then
    Label8.BackColor = vbGreen

    Temp1 = Right(PackingSNTextBox.Value, 7)
    Temp11 = CLng(Temp1)
    Temp1A = Temp11 + 1
    Temp1AA = CStr(Temp1A)
    Temp1B = Right("0000000" & Temp1AA, 7)
    Temp3 = Left(PackingSNTextBox.Value, 9)
    Temp2 = Temp3 & Temp1B

    'Determine emptyRow
    emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

    'Transfer information
    Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Label13
    Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Label14
    Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Now
    Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = PartSNTextBox.Value
    Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = PackingSNTextBox.Value

    NextSNTextBox.Value = Temp2
    Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Temp2
    PartSNTextBox.Value = ""
    PackingSNTextBox.Value = ""
    PartSNTextBox.SetFocus    
Else
    ClearButton.Enabled = False
    Label9.BackColor = vbRed
    MsgBox ("Wrong Pairing")
    PackingSNTextBox = ""
    PackingSNTextBox.SetFocus
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: to get the first **emptyRow** in column "A", use : `emptyRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1`

Comment: Besided that your code runs well with the User_form I've tested, what values are you using in `PartSNTextBox` ?

Comment: Hi Shai Rado, the values that will be key in is 123456789AA0000001 (9 integer+2 aphablet + 7 integer. The weird thing is my result will shows correct answer on the excel cells but  "Run Time Error 13" will appear.

Comment: `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If Cells(2, 8) = "" Then
NextSNTextBox.Value = "123456789AA0000001"
Else
NextSNTextBox.Value = Cells(2, 8).Value
End If

PartSNTextBox.Value = ""

Label11.BackColor = 1
Label12.BackColor = 1

PackingSNTextBox.Value = ""

Label8.BackColor = 1
Label9.BackColor = 1

PartSNTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub`

Comment: `Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Afterupdate()
If Not IsEmpty(PartSNTextBox) Then
Label11.BackColor = 1
Label12.BackColor = 1
Label8.BackColor = 1
Label9.BackColor = 1
End If

If PartSNTextBox.Value = NextSNTextBox.Value Then
Label12.BackColor = vbGreen
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = True

Else
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = False
Label11.BackColor = vbRed
MsgBox ("Wrong Serial Number")
PartSNTextBox = ""
PartSNTextBox.SetFocus

End If
End Sub

Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Enter()
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = True

End Sub`

Comment: `Private Sub PackingSNTextBox_Enter()
ClearButton.Enabled = True

End Sub
Private Sub ClearButton_Click()

Call UserForm_Initialize

End Sub
Private Sub CancelButton_Click()

Unload Me

End Sub`

Comment: I posted other part of code as maybe other part of code is causing fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AfterUpdate` event fires before the control's value is changed.  Use the `Change()` event instead.

Here is my simple test:

```
Private Sub PackingSNTextBox_AfterUpdate()
    lblPackingSNTextBox_AfterUpdate.Caption = "PackingSNTextBox_AfterUpdate: " & PartSNTextBox.Value
End Sub

Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Change()
     lblPartSNTextBox_Change.Caption = "PartSNTextBox_Change: " & PartSNTextBox.Value
End Sub
```

[image]

```
Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Change()

    Dim Temp1 As String, Temp1A As Long, Temp1B As String, Temp2 As String, Temp11 As Long, Temp1AA As String, Temp3 As String
    PartSNTextBox.Enabled = True

    If PartSNTextBox.Value = PackingSNTextBox.Value Then
        Label8.BackColor = vbGreen

        Temp1 = Right(PackingSNTextBox.Value, 7)
        Temp11 = getNumbersFromString(Temp1)
        Temp1A = Temp11 + 1
        Temp1AA = CStr(Temp1A)
        Temp1B = Right("0000000" & Temp1AA, 7)
        Temp3 = Left(PackingSNTextBox.Value, 9)
        Temp2 = Temp3 & Temp1B

        With Sheet1
            With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).Offset(1)
                'Transfer information
                .Value = Label13
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = Label14
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = PartSNTextBox.Value
                .Offset(0, 4).Value = PackingSNTextBox.Value
            End With
        End With

        NextSNTextBox.Value = Temp2
        Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = Temp2
        PartSNTextBox.Value = ""
        PackingSNTextBox.Value = ""
        PartSNTextBox.SetFocus
    Else
        ClearButton.Enabled = False
        Label9.BackColor = vbRed
        MsgBox ("Wrong Pairing")
        PackingSNTextBox = ""
        PackingSNTextBox.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub

Function getNumbersFromString(text As String) As Single
    Dim result As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        If Mid(text, i, 1) Like "[1-9.,]" Then result = result & Mid(text, i, 1)
    Next
    If Len(result) > 0 Then getNumbersFromString = CSng(s)
End Function
```

Comment: I had change to "Change". However, same "Run Time Error 13" appear too.

Comment: `Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Afterupdate()
If Not IsEmpty(PartSNTextBox) Then
Label11.BackColor = 1
Label12.BackColor = 1
Label8.BackColor = 1
Label9.BackColor = 1
End If

If PartSNTextBox.Value = NextSNTextBox.Value Then
Label12.BackColor = vbGreen
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = True

Else
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = False
Label11.BackColor = vbRed
MsgBox ("Wrong Serial Number")
PartSNTextBox = ""
PartSNTextBox.SetFocus

End If
End Sub

Private Sub PartSNTextBox_Enter()
PackingSNTextBox.Enabled = True

End Sub`

Comment: `Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If Cells(2, 8) = "" Then
NextSNTextBox.Value = "123456789AA0000001"
Else
NextSNTextBox.Value = Cells(2, 8).Value
End If

PartSNTextBox.Value = ""

Label11.BackColor = 1
Label12.BackColor = 1

PackingSNTextBox.Value = ""

Label8.BackColor = 1
Label9.BackColor = 1

PartSNTextBox.SetFocus

End Sub

Comment: I posted other part of code as maybe other part of code is causing fail

Comment: PackingSNTextBox must have a non-numeric character in it.   Scanners are programmed to prefix and suffix special characters to the barcode.  A line return at the end should not cause an issue but it might.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a crude function to return the numeric portion of a string.  Let me know it it works.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for your help. I had use your formula and with some modification to obtain what I want.